# How do you make a passwords which are 15 to 24 characters long and have at least one digit?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I know that you can use the complement to find this so one case could be that you have no digits which would be 10^24. I'm not sure where to go from here. I'm not sure what you need to subtract or what steps should I do next?

Comment: Please elaborate, because it is not at all clear what you are asking. If I had to make a password 15 to 24 characters long and containing at least one digit, I would run `makepasswd --minchars 15 --maxchars 24` repeatedly until it outputs a string with at least one digit, but that's probably not what you want...

Comment: Also, what is the character set the symbols are chosen from?  Do you want to know the number of possible passwords or a way to make one (which you should ask on stackoverflow).

Answer (score 3):

If you're allowing $N$ different characters, then the number of strings that are $15$ to $24$ characters long is
$$
N^{15}+N^{16}+\ldots+N^{24}=\frac{N^{25}-N^{15}}{N-1}.
$$
To restrict this to passwords containing at least one digit, subtract the number of strings that are $15$ to $24$ characters long and use only the $(N-10$) non-digit characters.  The result is
$$
\frac{N^{25}-N^{15}}{N-1}-\frac{(N-10)^{25}-(N-10)^{15}}{N-11}.
$$
For instance, if you're just allowing alphanumeric characters, then $N=62$, and the number of legal passwords is about $1.042\times 10^{43}$.

Answer (score 1):

The total number of passwords with $s$ symbols and lengths from 15 to 24 is:
\begin{equation}
N_s = \sum_{15 \le l \le 24} s^l = s^{15} \frac{s^{10} - 1}{s - 1}
\end{equation}
What you need is (all passwords) - (passwords without digits):
\begin{equation}
N_{36} - N_{26}
\end{equation}